# How to enable automatic LaTeX math preview in org-mode/Emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, preview, org-mode

I am using org-mode 8.0, Emacs 24.3, Auctex 11.87, in Windows.

I was able to use LaTeX preview functions in org-mode files by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. However, I think it would be more useful if the math preview can be done automatically when the cursor leaves the math equation, e.g. for `$$a=b+c$$`, when my cursor is out of `$$`, Emacs should automatically enable preview. This may not be so important for .tex file, but is quite useful for org-mode, especially when you input equations during note taking, you want instantaneous preview.

I thought that *latex-math-preview.el* should provide such function but seems it is just another implementation of *preview-latex.el*.

How to enable automatic LaTeX math preview in org-mode/Emacs?

Comment: Looks like we now have a solution to this, thanks to John Kitchin: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/10/09/Automatic-latex-image-toggling-when-cursor-is-on-a-fragment/

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...An ugly and not imperfect solution:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "$") (lambda ()
                                     (interactive)
                                     (insert "$")
                                     (save-excursion
                                       (left-char 1)
                                       (if (org-inside-LaTeX-fragment-p)
                                           (progn
                                             (right-char 2)
                                             (org-preview-latex-fragment))))))
```

Anyway, it works on some degree.